# I am getting null pointer exception in Blackberry MAP application

Tags: java, blackberry, dictionary

```
if(map_field[i]==field){
  dealersObj=(WebCardDealersObject)data.elementAt(i);
  double lat=Double.parseDouble(dealersObj.getLatitude());
  double lang=Double.parseDouble(dealersObj.getLangitude());
  String str=dealersObj.getdealersTitle().toString();
  //dealersObj=(WebCardDealersObject)data.elementAt(i);
  //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MapForBankLocation(dealersObj.getLatitude(),dealersObj.getLangitude()));        }

  String document = "<lbs>" + "<location x='"+lat+"' y='"+lang+"' label='"+str+", ON'/>"+"</lbs>";
  Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT, document));
}
```

I run this in the Blackberry simulator, it then shows four times: `nullPointerException`.
Next it displays no data in MAP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `dealersObj` is `null`.  Have you verified that you are getting expected value(s) there?

Comment: have you debugged to find out exactly where the nullpointer is being thrown?  Whenever I run into an NPE, it is usually because I am making incorrect assumptions about where a `null` may or may not be passed to/returned from a function.